# Set conditions on routing rules in symfony 1.x

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

With symfony 1.4 I'm using this rule:

```
asasds:
  url:    /users/:order
  param:  { module: users, action: index }
```

I want to achieve this: `www.mysite.com/users/aNumericValueAsOrder` so far it looks ok, but what if I have an action `www.mysite.com/users/createOrder` as FORM POST action. `createOrder()` is a method, not an numeric id.

How to distinguish? How to tell it to the routing system that "please check whether it is an action"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
asasds:
  url:    /users/:order
  param:  { module: users, action: index }
  requirements: { order: \d+ }
```

That's for numeric values, of course; the requirements subparams are regular expressions, so are very flexible.

Comment: hm I didnt think its that easy, first I thought I have to set more rules for each actions

Comment: @user1929946 - in general I would make that `/order/:order` (i.e. in the singular form) and create a new route `/orders/create` - that makes a bit more sense, as well as being easier to write rules for.

Comment: Remember also that if you have two rules that have the same form, put the most specific requirements first (e.g. numbers only) so that the most permissive ones only get matched as a last resort.